# Require function with variable

Tags: php

can you tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
require( 'prepareOrder.php?oID='.$orders["id"].'');
```

Where: prepareOrder.php is a php located on the webpage root folder
and `orders[id]` is an id from an sql database.

Comment: This looks more like PHP than anything to do with PHP. Anyway, `require()` cannot accept `GET` variables as part of the path.

Comment: Do you have a ***file on disk*** which is named `prepareOrder.php?oID=42`? Didn't think so...

Comment: You can acces super globals let say `$_GET $_POST` in file as you are access in the main file ;)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Except this isn't a super-global, it's `$orders`.

Comment: @BenM if you have a look over `require( 'prepareOrder.php?oID='.$orders["id"].'');` @Levi is trying to get `oID` through `$_GET` in prepareOrder.php right or not? ;)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 True, but the value the OP is assigning to the `oID` `GET` param isn't itself a super-global, so he won't be able to access it via `$_GET` inside of `prepareOrder.php`...

Comment: You mean `$_GET` is not a superglobal in PHP? ;)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 No, that's not what I'm saying at all.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, `require()` is only getting the file name. This means if you `require('somefile.php?somevar=somevalue');` this will check if a file called `somefile.php?somevar=somevalue` exists. I "guess" you dont have this file with that name :)
So, if you need to pass parameters to an included file, you just need to declare those parameters before including the file.
Example: If you need to include `somefile.php` and use `$somevar` inside it, this is how to do it:

```
$somevar = 'somevalue';
include('somefile.php');
```

or

```
require('somefile.php');
```

and then you can use `$somevar` inside `somefile.php` without any problem :)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: What i wanted to achieve, is after the php has finished it-s operations, to open a new page, called prepareOrder.php and add the id of the order in the link.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all no such file exists in your system having ? in name

All the variables declared before file include/require are available in that file and variables declared in included/required file are also available in parent file.

So simply include file and access variables as you access in other files ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters when requiring or including a file. It is not executed as a web request, but simply included in the source - imagine copy and pasting the source code contents of the file, not the end result.

See the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for `include()`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `require()` function does not accept `GET` parameters as part of the request path.

As a result, PHP is looking for a file which is *physically* named `prepareOrder.php?oID=1` (assuming `$orders["id"]` = `1`)

You should, however, be able to access the `$orders` array inside of your `prepareOrder.php` file, so you can utilise the `id` key within your required file.

Comment: Thank you BenM, i have included the id variable in the prepareOrder.php file, but i have an if statement that is not passing in this way:

 if (!isset($_REQUEST["oID"]) || !is_numeric($_REQUEST["oID"])) {
  die("Invalid Order. Please check the order access link!");
 }